# cookie doesn't get sent on first request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, middleware

I've got the following code on my **server.js** express application:

```
﻿var express = require('express');
var fallback = require('express-history-api-fallback');
var compress = require('compression');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var prerenderio = require('prerender-node');
var config = require('getconfig');

var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (config.environment !== 'local') {
        res.cookie('config', JSON.stringify(config), { secure: true });
    }
    else {
        res.cookie('config', JSON.stringify(config));
    }
    next();
});

app.get('/versioncheck', function(req, res) {
    return res.json({ version: config.version });
});

app.use(compress());
app.use(prerenderio.set('prerenderToken', config.prerender_token).set('protocol', 'https'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname, { maxAge: 31536000 }));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/favicon.ico'));
app.use(fallback('index.html', { root: __dirname }));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1010;

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port %s', PORT);
});
```

The first middleware I'm setting up with express is quite simple: It sends down a cookie to the client with some config information. The issue I'm facing is that this cookie doesn't get sent down to the client upon first request. For all subsequent requests it does work fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago.

At the begin of the first request, the cookie does not exist.

The cookies get sent during the request, not before.

So, at the begin of the second request, the cookie is set (from request 1).

Comment: I see your point but in other words you're saying I can never get a cookie from the server and read it on the client in the very first request?

Comment: That is what i wanted to point out. Maybe you can add a tag to your html header, or use the # tag in the url.

Comment: I'm still doing more investigation on this. The odd thing is that if I request mysite.com for the first time he cookie doesn't get set. However, if I request mysite.com/foo also for the first time, the cookie gets set.

Comment: I know, there shouldnt be any difference, but try `app.use("*", function (req, res, next) {`

Comment: that didn't do the trick ... I've changed a few things and seemed to have fixed it. Will monitor my app before posting the answer.

Comment: Any answer to this question please?